# PHP - What to use for database encryption if not MD5?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, md5, sha

Okay, I don't know if this has been asked before, but there's a lot of sources stating that it's not recommended to use MD5 for hashing sensitive data like passwords for example. But nobody gave any recommendations or indications towards what other hashing function they would use. All that you see, including on this site is people ranting back and fourth that it is or it's not safe.

As we all know, Wikipedia says:

> "In 1996 a flaw was found in the design of MD5. While it was not a
>   clearly fatal weakness, cryptographers began recommending the use of
>   other algorithms, such as SHA-1—which has since been found to be
>   vulnerable as well."

This is quoted around by the people that tell you not to use md5 or sha1, but they don't want to enlighten everybody else towards what other alternatives you should consider.

Of course let's not forget that the way you design your application, where you store your keys, who has access to what, using a salt etc is also very and certainly more important.

Of course verifying and validating all data, not leaving any back doors open for SQL injection, XSS vulnerabilities is key. But from what I learned, md5 can be easily "brute forced" or "desalted". I'm not a security guru, this is why I ask so I and anyone that's as experienced as I am can understand in more simple terms.

This is what I am doing at the moment but maybe somebody can give me pros and cons:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . hash('sha256', $_POST['pass']) );
```

I hope my question isn't out of line, I know there is a lot of articles and pages on this, but I just haven't found any answers, and I am sure others would like to know as well.

Comment: Whenever you describe hashing as encryption an innocent bunny rabbit dies.

Comment: My first thought was sha 256 / sha 512 / etc.. Think about dynamic salt as well (such as a substring of the username or something).  That way every persons salt could be different.

Comment: check blowfish implementation http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/blowfish-crypt/

Answer (score 5):

Since PHP 5.5 you can use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

```
/**
 * In this case, we want to increase the default cost for BCRYPT to 12.
 * Note that we also switched to BCRYPT, which will always be 60 characters.
 */
$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];

echo password_hash("Stack Overflow", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
```

Comment: If you're running an old version of PHP, go get the compat functions: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat. Either way, stop trying to solve this on your own and implement existing best practices!

Comment: I previous versions, just use `crypt` directly: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php (`password_hash` is simply a wrapper around the lower level crypt functions)

Comment: @troelskn That's a bit annoying since you need to take care of the salt yourself. The `password_compat` is definitely easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this several times. many of my friends use it, as I said also because it has something good and there is a good explain things
[Link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough)